# publish_actions scope is not working for the created app in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am using publish_actions to post on my wall the content from my website.I am the admin of the app which i have create .But while logging to facebook the permission for publish_actions doesnt shows up it only shows the permission for public profile.I have mentioned my scope lik this:

$fb=Yii::app()->facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' =>Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)."/jobs/fbscall",'scope'=>'publish_actions'));

Comment: are you sure you are trying as app admin? sounds like a review thing to me.

Comment: ya i am the administrator of the app .

Comment: btw, you are not supposed to ask for read and publish permissions at the same time. only ask for publish permissions right before you really need them. it´s somewhere in the facebook rules. debug the access token though, and see if the permission is in there. your question is not very detailed, so we can only make assumptions where the problem may be. any errors you get when you try to post? did you authorize the app? i think the publish permission will get asked in a separate screen.

Comment: i am the creator of the app then why i have to go for review process?facebook already provided in specification developer of the app doesnt need any review process to access extended permissions

Comment: you don´t have to to through review for testing, of course. what i mean is that you may try with another user without knowing. a lot of things can be the issue here.

Comment: The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: offcourse i am asking for only publishing permission here in my scope

Comment: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action this was the error i am receiving

Comment: i have only one facebook id i am trying only with that acting as administrator to that app here

Comment: publish permission has shown in separate screen only i cannot post theory here ..i have provided in brief the issue...

Comment: i have debugged the access token to it doesnt have the publish_actions scope but i have provided in my program

Comment: solved this question  ..by adding permission via graph explorer ..

Answer (score 0):

To get extended permissions, you must submit your APP for review. These permissions you get pre-approved for your Facebook Application:

o) **email**: 
Provides access to the person's primary email address. This permission is approved by default.

o) **public_profile**: 
Provides access to a person's basic information, including first name, last name, profile picture, gender and age range. This permission is approved by default.

o) **user_friends**: 
Provides access to a person's list of **friends that also use your app**. This permission is approved by default.

*Your app can ask for additional permissions at any time, even after a person logs in for the first time. For example, for the publish_actions permission. It's recommended you ask for this permission only when a person is ready to publish a story to Facebook. When you ask for new permissions, the person using your app will be asked about those new permissions and has the ability to opt out.*

**Additionally publishing permissions (publish_actions) will prompt a second step in the Login dialog, which can cause fewer people to log in.**

For web apps, use a graph API endpoint to retrieve a list of granted permissions:

```
GET /{user-id}/permissions
```

The call must be made with either a **user access token** or your **app access token**. The call will return a **JSON** string containing the permission names which have been granted to the app and their status:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "**publish_actions**",
      "status": "**granted**"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "declined"
    }
  ]
}
```